# Check type of optional parameter in PHP

Tags: php

I am checking the type of optional parameters in PHP like this:

```php
/**
 * Get players in the team using limit and
 * offset.
 *
 *
 * @param TeamInterface $participant
 * @param int $limit
 * @param int $offset
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
 * @return Players of a team
 */
public function getPlayers(TeamInterface $team, $limit = null, $offset = null)
{
    if (func_num_args() === 2 && !is_int($limit) ){
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('"Limit" should be of int type, "%s" given respectively.', gettype($limit)));
    }
    if (func_num_args() === 3 && (!is_int($limit) || !is_int($offset))){
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('"Limit" and "Offset" should be of int type, "%s" and "%s" given respectively.', gettype($limit), gettype($offset)));
    }
//.....

}
```

This works but there are 2 main issues with this:

1/ If I need to check the type of 4/5 optional parameters for the same `int` type, the code become unnecessarily long. Any ideas how to make this piece of code more maintainable? (Maybe use only one `if` statement to check the same type of both `$limit` and `$offset`)

2/ `getPlayers($team, 2, null)` throws an exception. Is this ok knowing that the function can actually handle a `null` value here?

Comment: What does version have to do with this?

Comment: I didn't realize type hinting was already in use

Comment: @Patt, I have updated my answer, with a safe way to validate the function call request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a for loop with an array of args. Something like:

```
$args = func_get_args();
for ($i = 1; $i < 4; $i++) {
    if ($args[$i] !== null and !is_int($args[$i])) {
        throw ...
    }
}
```

Of course, adjust the for conditions based on your number of arguments that need to be checked.

Or...

```
$args = func_get_args();
// skip first
array_shift($args);
foreach ($args as $arg) {
    if ($arg !== null and !is_int($arg)) {
        throw ...
    }
}
```

Comment: @Patt, Do you only require to check if all are integer or? There are variable conditions for each occurence.

Comment: Why not use a `foreach` loop on `$args`.

Comment: foreach would work combined with array_shift() before the loop in order to skip the first parameter. I didn't do it that way for any particular reason. Answer updated to include both for educational purposes.

Comment: Well done! That's exactly what I was after. +1 for `array_shift`.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For 1) I would check each variable individually and throw an exception for each:

```
   if (!is_int($limit)){
        //Throw
    }
    if (!is_int($offset))){
        //Throw
    }
```

This still requires an if statement for each variable but is a bit less verbose.

For 2) if null values are allowed you can change the check to be something like:

```
if ($offset && !is_int($offset))){
    //Throw
}
```

Finally I wouldn't recommend checking `func_num_args()`. In your example code calling your function with too many arguments would bypass the validation.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I prefer to have only one argument per function (unless the function is very simple), For example the function can take `$request`, and returns a tree of data `$response`.  It makes it a bit easier to loop over and extend later:

```
function dostuff( $request ) {

   $team   = @$request['team'];
   $limit  = @$request['limit'];
   $offset = @$request['offset'];

   // ...
   return $response;
}
```

Then for validation, you can write a set of rules at the top of the function like

```
   // define validation rules
   $rules = array( 'required' => array('team'),      
                   'depends' => array('offset' => 'limit'),      
                   'types' => array('offset' => 'int', 'limit' => 'int' ),
            );
```

And centralize all your error checking in one call:

```
   // can throw exception
   argcheck( array( 'request' => $request, 'rules' => $rules ) );
```

This might need optimization, but the general approach helps contain bloat as you increase the complexity of the functions.

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't have type hints for scalars yet.

### Redesign

When you start to take a lot of optional arguments in your function you develop code smells.  Something is wrong, there is an object waiting to emerge.

Build all of your optional parameters as an Object and have a validate method on it.

I think you want a GameParameters object and have a validate method on it.

```
getPlayers($gameParameters) {
}
```

Move your validation of the parameters to that object where you can build it into each setter or have a comprehensive validate() function.

### Combinatorial problem

As far as the explosion of checks goes I would build an array of errors and throw that if there are errors.  This can be done with or without redesign.

```
if ($limit != null && !is_int($limit){
  #add to the errors array      
}

if ($offset != null && !is_int($offset){
  #add to the errors array      
}

if (errors) {
  throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('"Limit" and "Offset" should be of int type, "%s" and "%s" given respectively.', gettype($limit), gettype($offset)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use switch to code specific functions.

```
switch(gettype($limit)) {
    case "integer":
        //do other processing
    break;
}
```

You cannot leave your code vulnerable like that. As for a safe solution to overcome the vulnerabilities. Create a safe list like this.

```
public function getPlayers(TeamInterface $team, $limit = null, $offset = null) {
    $safelist = array("var1" => "TeamInterface", "var2" => "integer", "var3" => "integer");
    $args = function_get_args();
    $status = true;
    foreach($args as $key => $var) {
        if(gettype($var)!=$safelist["var".$key]) {
             $status = false;
             break;
        }
    }
    if(!$status) break;

    //...........
}
```

Comment: Many thanks @Starx. I already use `gettype()` when throwing the exception

Comment: Then I need to do the same thing for `$offset` etc... this becomes very long. I want to throw one exception for a specific type for all arguments that require that type.